# Script running on Firefox showing error

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Showing Error while running script by using Firefox 
With user of Roo & test/unit
I call information from excel sheet & user in executing but showing error 
Showing Error as below

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/ffi/platform.rb:2
: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
Started ChromeDriver
port=52228
version=20.0.1133.0
log=D:\chromedriver.log
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `read_nonblock': An existing c
nnection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (Errno::ECONNRESET)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_
equest'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1064:in `head'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/
elenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:62:in `block in stop'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:557:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/
elenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:58:in `stop'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/
elenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:52:in `block in start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/
elenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:124:in `block in exit_hook'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing diffrent error for script running on Firefox & chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811399/showing-diffrent-error-for-script-running-on-firefox-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have latest ffi gem installed.

`gem install ffi`

Then give it a shot.